# Conditional select show/hide items

Tags: jquery, selection, parent-child

I have this conditional select which generally works fine, but I would like to make some small tweaks. See my [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tWykv/).

If you select a brand, say, Apple, you get to select two models. If you select a model it works fine.

But (a) if you click "Select model" again (still with "Apple" selected in the first box), I would like to display all Apple items like before.

And (b) if you select another Apple model, nothing happens.

I guess the solution is in the `if ($currentSelection != "showall") {}`-statement, but I can't get it to work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tWykv/2/).

You were lacking some conditions:

```
if ($currentSelection != "showall") {
  $options.each(function(){
    if($(this).is("#"+$currentSelection)) //Show match
      $(this).parent().parent().fadeIn();
  });
  $options.not("#" + $currentSelection).parent().parent().fadeOut(); //Hide don't match
} else if($currentSelection == "showall"){ //If 'Select model'
  $options.parent().parent().fadeIn();
} else {
  $options.children().filter("." + $selectprod.val()).fadeIn();
}
```

If selected a model, you need to show all the options first so that the hidden options will be shown.

Comment: That's sweet. Works perfectly. Thanks a lot.